# How to reveal content behind a div with pure css?

Tags: css, html, z-index, transparency

I have an animated div (1) that goes on top another div (2). Div2's background and text color are the same as the body, so it is "invisible" to the naked eye- it just blends with the background. I would like so that when div1 passes over div2, div2's contents are revealed (the text).

I had thought of doing this first by setting the z-index of both divs on the same plane, then making div1 completely transparent so it reveals what's behind it, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here you can see what I'm talking about.

http://dabblet.com/gist/6034480

The text is there in blue if you can't tell. I want the eraser div to reveal the parent div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you're facing has to do with [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), simply move the `.eraser` div so that it is not a child of `.parent` and play with the z-index and position, or you can use a negative z-index.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/bZh2K/)**

**[Working Example with negative z-index](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/bZh2K/1/)**

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <p>HEllo World HEllo World HEllo World HEllo World HEllo World HEllo World HEllo World HEllo World HEllo World HEllo WorldHEllo World HEllo World HEllo World HEllo World HEllo World HEllo World HEllo World HEllo World HEllo World HEllo World HEllo World HEllo World HEllo World</p>
</div>
<div class="eraser"></div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: blue;
}
.parent {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 125px auto;
    padding: 15px;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    color: blue;
    z-index:3;
}
.eraser {
    left:180px;
    top: 60px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 0px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    transform-origin: left;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    transition: width .3s linear;
    transform: rotate(110deg);
    /*box-shadow: 0 0 100px 50px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);*/
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
body:hover .eraser {
    width: 210px;
    transition: width .2s;
}
```

Comment: Wow that's exactly what I was looking for! So does parent div just have a transparent background? Also, in my actual site, I want the text to be a link instead. Is there a way to make the link active/clickable only when it is revealed by the eraser div?

Comment: The parent div doesn't have a background at all, the eraser div is dropping between the parent div and the body. As far as the link issue, you may have to do some research or ask a new question, but you could just put a cover div over the whole thing and slide it out as the eraser slides in.

Answer (score 0):

you can use css pseudo selector like '+' in css

like

```
.classtext:hover + .eraser {left:50px;}
```

note '+' is like before, so eraser class should be first placed first before .classtext will be second